# PHP undefined variable weird

Tags: php, variables

Here's my script it verifies wether a `username` has been taken.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $usname=$row['Username'];
}
if ($usname!=$uname)
{

} else {
  echo "Username taken!";
  die;
}
```

It works well. If a `username` is taken, it does not add it to the database, and will if it is unclaimed. But I always get this annoying error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: usname in C:\xampp\htdocs\insert.php on line 29

I defined that variable!

Help...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**warning**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @teresko I don't use mysql_ functions. Notice how the answers use mysql_? Uh huh. This question was asked in November, before myqli or PDO. Now I use myqli. Please check the asking date before making dumb comments.

Comment: MySQLi was introduced in PHP 5.0, PDO was introduced in 5.1 version. Also, your question IS using `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: I didn't deny my question used mysql_. However, three answers use mysql_, and no one commented until you, two days ago. Back when I asked the question w3school's page had a mysql_ example (now they use mysqli_ in their examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define $usname

```
$usname = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

If `mysql_fetch_array()` returns `null` your while-loop will never launch, thus `$usname` will never be initialized.

Try declaring it on the line above, like this:

```
$usname = null;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $usname=$row['Username'];
}
If ($usname!=$uname)
{

}else{
   echo "Username taken!";
   die;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not declared `$usname` as a variable.  Try putting `$usname='';` before the while loop

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```